# Is there a way to apply a formula to two vectors of values and getting a dataframe with the output for each combination?

Tags: r

For example if i have the following vectors:

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(2,5,4,2)
```

And the operation would be to just multiply the values i would expect the output:

```
 *  [1] [2] [3]
[2]  2   4   6
[5]  5  10  15
[4]  4   8  12
[2]  2   4   6
```

Is there a way to do this in R without just running some loops? The operation im looking to run is

```
f(x,y) = (EXP(1*(x-y)))/(1+EXP(x-y))
```

and the vectors are just two numerical vectors, one has around 50000 values, the other around 25.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `outer` to do this by passing the function in `FUN`

```
outer(b, a, FUN = function(x, y) exp(1*(x-y))/(1 + exp(x - y)))
```

and to get the `*`

```
outer(b, a)
```

Comment: `outer(a, b, FUN = function(x, y) 1/(1 + exp(y-x)))` also

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thank you very much